# A beginner's question of Riemannian Geometry.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

In picture below ,I don't know why $\Phi^{-1}(F)=(F(\phi^i,e_j))_{i,j=1}^n$

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{e_j\}$ is a basis on $V$. $\{\phi_i\}$ the complementary basis on $V^*$. That is, for all $i,j, \phi_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Now if $A\in \operatorname{End}(V)$, then $\Phi(A)(\phi_i, e_j) = \phi_i(A(e_j)) = A_{ij}$, that is, the entry in the $i^\text{th}$ row and $j^\text{th}$ column of the matrix representation of $A$ with respect to the basis $\{e_j\}$. Letting $\Phi(A) = F$, we see that $A_{ij} = F(\phi_i, e_j)$.

This is what is meant by $\Phi^{-1}(F)=(F(\phi^i,e_j))_{i,j=1}^n$

Comment: $\Phi^{-1}(F)=A=\{A_{ij}\}=(F(\phi^i,e_j))_{i,j=1}^n$,yes or no ?

Comment: I would not represent the matrix for $A$ by $\{A_{ij}\}$ ever, But if you interpret $(F(\phi^i,e_j))_{i,j=1}^n$ as "the endomophism of $V$ whose matrix with respect $e_i$ has these elements", then yes, the rest of that is true.